# Android issues when building, JPG

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a JPG file to my app. But it dont like the capital letters in "JPG". Anyone knows how to fix this?

```
Error:Error: Invalid file name: must contain only lowercase letters and digits ([a-z0-9_.])
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
C:\Users\**\Documents\DEV\PO\**\app\src\main\res\drawable\sabtest.JPG: Error: Invalid file name: must contain only lowercase letters and digits ([a-z0-9_.])
```

I'm not sure I did that code part right either...
Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the filename to contain only lowercase letters and digits, as is indicated in the error message. Underscores are also allowed.

So, rename the file to be `sabtest.jpg`.

For example, given an Android Studio project with the resource from your question:

[image: flawed drawable resource name]

Click on the file in question, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> (Windows/Linux; there should be an OS X equivalent) and edit the filename in the dialog:

[image: refactoring dialog]

Click "Refactor" and (perhaps a confirmation dialog or two later), the file will be renamed:

[image: fixed drawable resource name]

Comment: @QuiteNice: I do not know what "it" is in your comment. Most Android IDEs and OS file managers are capable of renaming files without adding `.JPG` to the end of those files.

Comment: Thanks! Editing in Android Studio changed the ending. When I edited in Windows it would not allow me to changes the .JPG

Comment: @QuiteNice: That's odd. I have no idea why Windows would be trying to force the file extension that way. Regardless, I am glad that you got it working.